Form size is not responsive with any screens
I've been trying to make my form responsive that fit in any screen. This form attached to a panel. I have marked that panel in red box in this image. This form inside the panel(showed in red box) is fit well in another screen. but my screen show like this.

What i have done here is, I have created a main form called MainDashboard.cs and on top of that i have add a menu left and a panel right side which is showing the forms that user select from the menu. The problem is panel is not fitted with the form which displays through it.
Here is the MainDashboard.cs code.
namespace Invenova.Forms
{
    partial class MainDashboard
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 109);
            this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1356, 759);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // MainDashboard
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(120F, 120F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1202, 659);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel6);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 10.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 3, 4, 3);
            this.Name = "MainDashboard";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "MainDashboard";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainDashboard_Load);
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel3.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel3.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.panel6.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button7;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button5;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button button4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button13;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button6;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button8;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button9;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    }
}

Here is the form code, that i'm trying to display in the panel in MainDashboard.cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Invenova.Forms
{
    partial class SellsForm
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SelsList = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
            this.NItems = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.Total = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.Discount = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.STotal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.NDiscount = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.NQuentity = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.ItemPrice = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.Remove = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Add = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.Bill = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.ItemNameCombo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.BarCodeCombo = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.PMode = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.showBalance = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.PayAmount = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.save = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.list = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.NDiscount)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.NQuentity)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PayAmount)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // SelsList
            // 
            this.SelsList.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
            this.SelsList.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.SelsList.HideSelection = false;
            this.SelsList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(26, 247);
            this.SelsList.Name = "SelsList";
            this.SelsList.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1762, 928);
            this.SelsList.TabIndex = 6;
            this.SelsList.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            // 
            // NItems
            // 
            this.NItems.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.NItems.AutoSize = true;
            this.NItems.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1814, 247);
            this.NItems.Name = "NItems";
            this.NItems.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(179, 39);
            this.NItems.TabIndex = 1;
            this.NItems.Text = "No. Items :";
            // 
            // Total
            // 
            this.Total.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Total.AutoSize = true;
            this.Total.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1816, 313);
            this.Total.Name = "Total";
            this.Total.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(107, 39);
            this.Total.TabIndex = 2;
            this.Total.Text = "Total :";
            // 
            // Discount
            // 
            this.Discount.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Discount.AutoSize = true;
            this.Discount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1814, 379);
            this.Discount.Name = "Discount";
            this.Discount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 39);
            this.Discount.TabIndex = 3;
            this.Discount.Text = "Discount :";
            // 
            // STotal
            // 
            this.STotal.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.STotal.AutoSize = true;
            this.STotal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1813, 445);
            this.STotal.Name = "STotal";
            this.STotal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(173, 39);
            this.STotal.TabIndex = 4;
            this.STotal.Text = "Sub Total :";
            // 
            // NDiscount
            // 
            this.NDiscount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1195, 72);
            this.NDiscount.Name = "NDiscount";
            this.NDiscount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(174, 47);
            this.NDiscount.TabIndex = 3;
            this.NDiscount.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.RecordeChange);
            // 
            // NQuentity
            // 
            this.NQuentity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1008, 72);
            this.NQuentity.Minimum = new decimal(new int[] {
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.NQuentity.Name = "NQuentity";
            this.NQuentity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 47);
            this.NQuentity.TabIndex = 3;
            this.NQuentity.Value = new decimal(new int[] {
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.NQuentity.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.RecordeChange);
            // 
            // ItemPrice
            // 
            this.ItemPrice.AutoSize = true;
            this.ItemPrice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 157);
            this.ItemPrice.Name = "ItemPrice";
            this.ItemPrice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(191, 39);
            this.ItemPrice.TabIndex = 12;
            this.ItemPrice.Text = "Item Price :";
            // 
            // Remove
            // 
            this.Remove.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Remove.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.Remove.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.Remove.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Remove.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Remove.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1276, 140);
            this.Remove.Name = "Remove";
            this.Remove.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 72);
            this.Remove.TabIndex = 13;
            this.Remove.Text = "Remove";
            this.Remove.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Remove.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ClickRemove);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.button2.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.button2.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.button2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1045, 140);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 72);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button2.Text = "Clear";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Add
            // 
            this.Add.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Add.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.Add.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.Add.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Add.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Add.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(807, 140);
            this.Add.Name = "Add";
            this.Add.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(208, 72);
            this.Add.TabIndex = 4;
            this.Add.Text = "Add";
            this.Add.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.Add.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Add_Click);
            // 
            // Bill
            // 
            this.Bill.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.Bill.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.Bill.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.Bill.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.Bill.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.Bill.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1821, 1087);
            this.Bill.Name = "Bill";
            this.Bill.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 88);
            this.Bill.TabIndex = 9;
            this.Bill.Text = "Bill (F10)";
            this.Bill.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.Bill.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Bill_Click);
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(19, 19);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 39);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 17;
            this.label2.Text = "Barcode";
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this.label3.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label3.AutoSize = true;
            this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(526, 19);
            this.label3.Name = "label3";
            this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(192, 39);
            this.label3.TabIndex = 18;
            this.label3.Text = "Item Name";
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this.label4.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label4.AutoSize = true;
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1000, 21);
            this.label4.Name = "label4";
            this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 39);
            this.label4.TabIndex = 19;
            this.label4.Text = "Quentity";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this.label5.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label5.AutoSize = true;
            this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1187, 19);
            this.label5.Name = "label5";
            this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(151, 39);
            this.label5.TabIndex = 20;
            this.label5.Text = "Discount";
            // 
            // ItemNameCombo
            // 
            this.ItemNameCombo.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.ItemNameCombo.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.ItemNameCombo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(534, 72);
            this.ItemNameCombo.Name = "ItemNameCombo";
            this.ItemNameCombo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(441, 47);
            this.ItemNameCombo.TabIndex = 1;
            this.ItemNameCombo.TextUpdate += new System.EventHandler(this.ItemNameComboBox_TextUpdate);
            this.ItemNameCombo.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.ItemName_Leave);
            // 
            // BarCodeCombo
            // 
            this.BarCodeCombo.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.BarCodeCombo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(27, 72);
            this.BarCodeCombo.Name = "BarCodeCombo";
            this.BarCodeCombo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(465, 47);
            this.BarCodeCombo.TabIndex = 0;
            this.BarCodeCombo.TextUpdate += new System.EventHandler(this.BarCodeComboBox_TextUpdate);
            this.BarCodeCombo.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.BarCode_Leave);
            // 
            // PMode
            // 
            this.PMode.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.PMode.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.PMode.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
            "CASH",
            "CARD"});
            this.PMode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1825, 713);
            this.PMode.Name = "PMode";
            this.PMode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(311, 47);
            this.PMode.TabIndex = 8;
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1820, 647);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(324, 39);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 25;
            this.label1.Text = "Payment Mode (F7)";
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this.label6.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            this.label6.AutoSize = true;
            this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1814, 511);
            this.label6.Name = "label6";
            this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(172, 39);
            this.label6.TabIndex = 26;
            this.label6.Text = "Cash (F6):";
            // 
            // showBalance
            // 
            this.showBalance.AutoSize = true;
            this.showBalance.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1817, 581);
            this.showBalance.Name = "showBalance";
            this.showBalance.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(156, 39);
            this.showBalance.TabIndex = 27;
            this.showBalance.Text = "Balance:";
            // 
            // PayAmount
            // 
            this.PayAmount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1992, 511);
            this.PayAmount.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
            -559939585,
            902409669,
            54,
            0});
            this.PayAmount.Name = "PayAmount";
            this.PayAmount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 47);
            this.PayAmount.TabIndex = 7;
            this.PayAmount.ValueChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.PayAmount_ValueChanged);
            // 
            // save
            // 
            this.save.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.save.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.save.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.save.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.save.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1820, 972);
            this.save.Name = "save";
            this.save.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 88);
            this.save.TabIndex = 28;
            this.save.Text = "save";
            this.save.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.save.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.save_Click);
            // 
            // list
            // 
            this.list.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(122)))));
            this.list.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.list.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.list.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.list.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1820, 857);
            this.list.Name = "list";
            this.list.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 88);
            this.list.TabIndex = 29;
            this.list.Text = "Saved List";
            this.list.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.list.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.list_Click);
            // 
            // SellsForm
            // 
            this.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Column;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(192F, 192F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
            this.AutoScroll = true;
            this.AutoSize = true;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(2170, 1215);
            this.Controls.Add(this.list);
            this.Controls.Add(this.save);
            this.Controls.Add(this.PayAmount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.showBalance);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.PMode);
            this.Controls.Add(this.BarCodeCombo);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ItemNameCombo);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Bill);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Add);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Remove);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ItemPrice);
            this.Controls.Add(this.NQuentity);
            this.Controls.Add(this.NDiscount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.STotal);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Discount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Total);
            this.Controls.Add(this.NItems);
            this.Controls.Add(this.SelsList);
            this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Arrow;
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Century Gothic", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "SellsForm";
            this.Text = "SellsForm";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.NDiscount)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.NQuentity)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PayAmount)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView SelsList;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label NItems;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label Total;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label Discount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label STotal;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown NDiscount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown NQuentity;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label ItemPrice;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Remove;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Add;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button Bill;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox ItemNameCombo;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox BarCodeCombo;
        //private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox CustomerNameCombo;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox PMode;
        private Label label1;
        private Label label6;
        private Label showBalance;
        private NumericUpDown PayAmount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button save;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button list;
    }
}


this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(225, 109); - Fixed Positions do not mix well with autosize. I think you need to pin that box of controls to the right of your grid to the right border of the enclosing panel and have the grid fill the remaining space.

Typically in Winforms design you solve such things with setting the Dock properties of the controls involved. If what we see is mostly designed with 2 panels side by side then set the Left one to Dock.Left and the other one to Dock.Client.

Sidenote Consider activating your Windows OS.

hi @Ralf Thank you for your comment. unfortunately, I didn't get the solution. could you please explain a bit?

Linked the docs with examples. After you tried those then we might talk about details if you still fail.

Check and try to modify your position and layout of controls, such as Dock and Anchor and etc., refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/layout?view=netdesktop-8.0
